Difference in the Coordinator for UIViewRepresentable and UIViewControllerRepresentable
Why does the Coordinator for UIViewRepresentable written so verbose? Given below are two fragments of code, one using UIViewRepresentable and one using UIViewControllerRepresentable:
struct CustomCameraView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> CustomCameraViewController {
        ...
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: CustomCameraViewController, context: Context) {
        ...
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject {
        var parent: CustomCameraView
        init(_ parent: CustomCameraView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
    }
} 

And with UIViewRepresentable:
struct CustomCameraView: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> CustomUIView {
        ...
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: CustomUIView, context: Context) -> CustomUIView {
        ...
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject {
        var parent: CustomCameraView
        init(_ parent: CustomCameraView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
    }
}

The UIViewRepresentable code complains about the following two things:

Nested class CustomCameraView.Coordinator has an unstable name when archiving via NSCoding.
Type CustomCameraView.Coordinator does not conform to the protocol NSCoding.

There are automatic ways to fix it:
@objc(CustomCameraView_Coordinator) class Coordinator: NSObject {
    var parent: CustomCameraView
    init(_ parent: CustomCameraView) {
        self.parent = parent
    }
    
    func encode(with Coder: NSCoder) {
        ...
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        ...
    }
}

My question is that, why does Coordinator work with UIViewControllerRepresentable but complains about these errors in UIViewRepresentable? Are the Coordinators for these implemented differently?

I'm using Xcode 16 and can compile your code succesfully

Not sure if it is the cause of the issue but it should be Coordinator() instead of Coordinator(self). self is value that will change when the view data changes so you can't hang on to it like it is an object reference.
